# "cp" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: npm, consola

Estoy tratando de contribuir a un proyecto de codigo abierto [Datatables](https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables). Y para empezar he tenido problemas para hacer funcionar todo, ya que es mi primera vez con empaquetadores y npm. Al ejecutar `npm install` obtengo el siguiente error:

```
"cp" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
 programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

cuando intenta ejecutar la siguiente linea:

```
cp src/style.css dist/style.css
```

Eso ocurre cuando se ejecutan estos scripts del package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "npm run check_js",
    "check_js": "eslint src/",
    "compile": "npm run compile_js && npm run compile_js_umd && npm run compile_css && npm run compile_demo",
    "compile_js": "rollup -c",
    "compile_js_umd": "browserify dist/index.js --standalone simpleDatatables -o dist/umd/simple-datatables.js",
    "compile_css": "cp src/style.css dist/style.css",
    "compile_demo": "npm run compile_demo_js && cp node_modules/systemjs/dist/s.min.js demo/dist/nomodule/ && cp src/style.css demo/dist/style.css",
    "compile_demo_js": "rollup -c rollup.demo.config.js",
    "postcompile_demo": "cp -r dist/umd demo/dist",
    "prepare": "npm run compile"
  }
```

exactamente el `compile-css`.

Lo extraño es que si lo ejecuto directamente funciona y en este caso `cp` me copia los archivos.
¿Como puedo solucionar este error?

Comment: y si cambias el comando `cp` por `copy`?, igual tienes que dejarlo para gnu/linux y para windows

Comment: Puedes crear un alias con `alias cp="copy"`, esto debería funcionar si estas en el sistema operativo Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas ejecutando tus scripts en Windows? En caso de ser así, ***cp*** no te funcionará si usas npm desde la CMD, intenta ejecutando npm desde Powershell ya que si adminte el comando ***cp***, también puedes intentar cambiando los comandos desde el package.json (el comando ***cp*** sería reemplazado por ***copy***) a modo de prueba. existe tambien este [paquete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os) que permite ejecutar scripts basados en tu sistema operativo.

Answer (score 0):

El error que corresponde a que no encuentra a 'cp' como comando es porque no esta el path de cp dentro de las variables globales del sistema.

para solucionar esto prueba el siguiente comando en la consola en la que estes usando el comando ( este metodo solo incluira el path de manera temporal )

en tu consola le das: SET PATH=el/path/de/carpeta;%PATH%;

por ejemplo. yo uso mucho mysql y a veces en otras pcs que no tienen instalada la variable, yo escribo algo asi

SET PATH=D:\Programas\Xampp\mysql\bin;%PATH%; ( un pequeño ejemplo con el de mysql que esta en xampp)

de esta misma forma pones a cp como variable global, y ahora si podrias usarla :)